# # Check for duplicates pandas

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

```
df.columns

Index(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email Address', 'Company', 'Position',
       'Connected On;'],
      dtype='object')
```

How I can remove 'Connected On;' I want to fix only "Connected On" with ou ';'

Comment: Please format your code, and clearly state your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply rename the column using: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

```
df = df.rename({'Connected On;':'Connected On'})
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you

Comment: look this https://towardsdatascience.com/linkedin-network-visualisation-using-plotly-9e1962247859

Comment: Which part would you like me to see?

Comment: df=df.sort_values(by="Connected On")

Show me error
-> 1706             raise KeyError(key)
   1707 
   1708         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'Connected On'

Comment: Look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html.